# Runtime COM exception on copying worksheets in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I keep running into

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC'

using the following code :

```
private void FilterButton_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Worksheet activeSheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;

            Excel.Worksheet newSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            newSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add();
            newSheet.Copy(activeSheet);
        }
```

on line

> newSheet.Copy(activeSheet);

Am I missing something here? I got the active sheet, I can get its properties like Name for example without running into errors, so that's not Null Reference. This happens only when I want to access certain columns / rows and when I want to pass values between sheets.

I'm looking for something similar to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178800.aspx) but in C#.

Comment: So is it this code that throws the error? On what line?

Comment: Google "excel error 1004 copy worksheet", you'll find a KB article and several high-ranking existing SO questions about it.

Comment: All of them seem related to VBA though.

Comment: It does not matter if you do this with VBA or C#, the underlying error cause is the same.

Comment: The issue there seems to be opening a new application instance and then copying and pasting. But I am not doing that, I am opening the current active application.

Comment: Some seem to have solved this issue by actually opening application with application.Workbooks.Open(path), but in my situation, the path can differ.